# Retrieve all records using Prestashop's ObjectModel

Tags: sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6, object-model

I've become a little too acquainted with working with SQL Queries directly and now making an effort to become equally acquainted with Prestashop's Active Record Pattern using it's ObjectModel class.

I'm attempting to load multiple records from a single table using ObjectModel, but not having much luck.  I've tried the following:

```
$units = new Unit(null, Context::getContext()->language->id);
```

I was hoping the above would perform the equivalent of "SELECT * FROM ps_unit WHERE id_lang = 1' which it obviously does not.

So my question is it possible to do a 'select *' using ObjectModel without writing a query?

Answer (score 2):

```
 $units = new PrestaShopCollection('unit')
```

This works if the class of your object model is called unit. If not, change the param to the real name.

After this, is possible to filter like this:

```
 $units->where('id_parent','=',$someValue)
```